Update multiple nodes using YQ
Istio recently introduced a CEL validation rule that conflicts with our custom go templating engine return errors such as this:
{"GenericComponent":{"name":"istio","namespace":"test-tbv-15"},"component":"cpc-operator","controller":"genericcomponent","controllerGroup":"cpc-operator.doks.digitalocean.com","controllerKind":"GenericComponent","egid":0,"eid":0,"env":"development","err":"failed to execute template \"istio/istio.yaml.tmpl\": template: istio.yaml.tmpl:265: invalid syntax","host":"local-cpcoperator","level":"error","msg":"Reconciler error","name":"istio","namespace":"test-tbv-15","pid":1,"pname":"/bin/cpc-operator","reconcileID":"e4298d85-7ad2-4dd4-944d-3e72d7e5d570","runtime_version":"go1.22.4","time":"2024-09-06T15:05:39.642835008Z","version":"b3337a879225e324581f73229bdadde47dd881d7"}

This is triggered by the formatting of the recently added CEL validation rule:
                x-kubernetes-validations:
                - message: Support kinds are core/Service and gateway.networking.k8s.io/Gateway
                  rule: '[self.group, self.kind] in [[''core'',''Service''], ['''',''Service''],
                    [''gateway.networking.k8s.io'',''Gateway'']]'

Using yq, I am able to identify the nodes that need updating:
cat $TEMPLATE_FILE | yq '.spec.versions[1].schema.openAPIV3Schema.properties.spec.properties.targetRef.x-kubernetes-validations[0].rule
This returns:
null
---
[self.group, self.kind] in [['core','Service'], ['','Service'], ['gateway.networking.k8s.io','Gateway']]
---
null
---
null
...

I can then filter the null values using the select operator:
yq '.spec.versions[0].schema.openAPIV3Schema.properties.spec.properties.targetRef.x-kubernetes-validations[0].rule | select (.)' 
Which returns:
[self.group, self.kind] in [['core','Service'], ['','Service'], ['gateway.networking.k8s.io','Gateway']]
---
[self.group, self.kind] in [['core','Service'], ['','Service'], ['gateway.networking.k8s.io','Gateway']]
---
[self.group, self.kind] in [['core','Service'], ['','Service'], ['gateway.networking.k8s.io','Gateway']]
---
[self.group, self.kind] in [['core','Service'], ['','Service'], ['gateway.networking.k8s.io','Gateway']]
---
[self.group, self.kind] in [['core','Service'], ['','Service'], ['gateway.networking.k8s.io','Gateway']]
---
...

I can not however perform an in place replacement of these entries. The following either alter the entire template file or nothing at all:
yq -i '.spec.versions[0].schema.openAPIV3Schema.properties.spec.properties.targetRef.x-kubernetes-validations[0].rule |= "test"' $TEMPLATE_FILE
yq -i  '.spec.versions[0].schema.openAPIV3Schema.properties.spec.properties.targetRefs.items.x-kubernetes-validations[0].rule | select(.) = "test"' $TEMPLATE_FILE 
What is the appropriate syntax to replace the value of the non-null nodes?

Add parens, so that traversal and selection become the LHS of the (update) assignment: (.spec.version[0] … .rule | select(.)) = "test" (or (… | …) |= … if the new value is based on the old one)

@pmf that adds the null nodes to the file instead where it previously didn't exist
